# Notifications won't appear in app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

my remote push notifications are appearing outside the app, but not while in the app.

This is how i configured my app delegate, as you can see in didRecieveRemoteNotification, i configured an alert to appear, which appears just fine inside the zoo, but I dont want an alert box, I want a top banner like the one outside the app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();


    return true

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    println("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    //Parsing userinfo:
    var temp : NSDictionary = userInfo
    if let info = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    {
        var alertMsg = info["alert"] as! String
        var alert: UIAlertView!
        alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: alertMsg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post a local notification instead of an alert view if that is the experience you want

Comment: i added this in didrecieveremotenotification            var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertAction = "Glimp"
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
            localNotification.alertBody = alertMsg
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Default")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a banner while the app is in the foreground, you will have to implement the banner yourself.  Banners are not shown for either a local or remote notification while the app is in the foreground.